# How to install q in another directory?

Tags: kdb

I am trying to install q in a directory other than my home directory. Is this possible? It seems q will fail if it is in another directory. I get this error when trying to run it:

```
'/Users/cammil/q/q.k. OS reports: No such file or directory
0::
`/Users/cammil/q/q.k
```

Answer (score 4):

Set your `QHOME` to directory which contains q.k file. That should solve the issue.

Also, if that directory does not contain k4.lic (license) file then set QLIC to directory containing license file.

Read more details about environment variables here: https://code.kx.com/q4m3/14_Introduction_to_Kdb+/#1481-the-environment-variables

Comment: What is missing from that documentation is the fact that two locations are used in the case that required `lic`, `q.k` and optional `q.q` are not found in their expected locations (`QHOME`, `QLIC` and `QINIT` respectively, with fallback to `QHOME`).

Both `$HOME/q` *and* the **directory of the q executable** are checked.



It's worth mentioning that the license check occurs **before** execution of `q.k`, and it may require an internet connection

Answer (score 3):

KDB+ uses the QHOME environment variable at startup. QHOME specifies where to find the q.k file, and if it is not defined kdb will by default look into the home directory. It will also look for the licence file in the same way. Therefore you must define your QHOME variable as the directory which holds the .q.k  and k4.lic files. (Or alternativley you can define the QLIC variable for the license)